# ExtJS 5.0 : Grid remoteSort always sorts by the default 'sorters' only

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, grid, store

I have an EXTJS Grid which has a buffered store. I have enabled remoteSort: true on this store. Several of the columns are marked sortable: true. But every time I click on any column for sorting, the backend call that is made only includes the sorters column and direction that is mentioned in the store. Ex. Even if I click on Col2 or Col3 for sorting, the GET call the backend always includes 'sort: col1, direction: desc', as mentioned in the 'sorters'.

Store:

```
Ext.define('MyStore', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
 model  : 'MyModel'

  pageSize: 200,
  autoLoad: false,
  leadingBufferZone: 200,
  trailingBufferZone: 200,
  remoteSort: true,
  sorters: [{
    property: 'col1',
    direction: 'DESC'
  }],

  proxy: {
    type  : 'rest',
    format: 'json',
    url   : '/my_app/my_controller/list',
    extraParams: {
      someparam: '',
      otherparam: ''
    },
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      rootProperty: 'data',
      totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    }
  }  
});
```

Grid:

```
Ext.define('MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    requires: [
    'MyStore'
    ],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = new MyStore();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    columns: [{
        text: 'Col1',
        dataIndex: 'col1',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true
    },{
        text: 'Col3',
        dataIndex: 'col3',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true
    },{
        text: 'Col3',
        dataIndex: 'col3',
        width: 250,
        sortable: true
    }]
});
```

How can I enable this grid to sort by any sortable column that is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary fix for bug in ExtJS 5.0. See: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?284772-remoteSort-doesn-t-work-with-BufferedStore

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.BufferedStore, { 
     sort: function(column, direction, mode){      
      this.getSorters().addSort(column, direction, mode);
      this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly set [`simpleSortMode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Server.html#cfg-simpleSortMode), and the documentation already mentions what the problem will be.

You have already set the first sorter, and sorting by column click adds a second sorter behind it, but only the first sorter is sent to the server when `simpleSortMode` is activated.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I removed simpleSortMode: true and still I see the same issue. With remoteSort: true and sorters mentioned, sorting by column click still only uses sorters. Also I tried remoteSort: false (to enable just local sorting) and that disables sorting entirely.

Comment: Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: [I have made a Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25t7) and found that the cause is an issue in 5.0.0. That bug is fixed in 5.0.1, you should consider a framework upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! I did think that it might be an ExtJS issue. I'll look into the upgrade. BTW, is it possible to use just local sorting?